# How to change column name into a variable

Tags: php, html

I've written a function which is gonna be used by my team and so far there are no specific actual column names in it except the columns in a **foreach loop**. I'd like to change them in to a variable so my team just change the variables in the given array instead of searching the entire code. Here's a snippet so you can see what I mean.

These are the **attributes** where you put in the **actual name of the column**.

```
$attributes = array("id", "firma", "vorname", "nachname", "straße", "hausnummer", "telefonnr", "dateien", "column", "column");
```

That's a row in my table which is displayed with **echo "code"** statement in php. Everytime I change the column name which is used by the **foreach loop** I'll get an error.

```
  <tr>  <!-- display data -->
  <td style='text-align:center;' width=" . $width[0] . ">$print->id</td>
  <td width=" . $width[1] . ">$print->firma</td>
  <td width=" . $width[2] . ">$print->vorname</td>
  <td width=" . $width[3] . ">$print->nachname</td>
  <td width=" . $width[4] . ">$print->straße</td>
  <td style='text-align:center;' width=" . $width[5] . ">$print->hausnummer</td>
  <td width=" . $width[6] . ">$print->telefonnr</td>
```

What I **tried** so far was

```
<td width=" . $width[1] . ">$print->" . $attributes[1] . "</td>
```

**or**

```
<td width=" . $width[1] . ">$print->$attributes[1]</td>
```

Is there a way to change the column name into a variable without getting errors?

Comment: Can you include the error?

Comment: Just get a error from the browser GUI. That something is not right. Is there a way to get a specific error code? then I'll attach it.

Comment: From the browser GUI.. You mean in the console? Or from php? Right now it's not clear if you have an error in your PHP or JS. Who also don't know what $width contains.

Comment: Anyhow, you need to open PHP tags if you want to use PHP variables

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea (IMHO) and you should stick with the database column names for accessing variables.

Comment: I tried that as well with php tags <?php ?> but didnt work out as well.
That'just HTML code and PHP. no java script.